# vertical spacing in safari

Tags: html, css, safari

Safari drops text a line below while Firefox reproduces what I intended.

See http://www.wordpix.ca/onepage/test.html

The code is here:

```
<style type ="text/css">
<!--
.button{
    height:20px;
    width:150px;
    float:left;
    border:solid thin red;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-left:10px;
    padding-left:5px;
}
-->
</style>
 <div class="button">Learn more:</div>
       <div class="button">Sign me up!</div>
       <div class="button">See sample pages</div>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me in Safari.

Comment: Which version of Safari? 4 or 5 (maybe on Windows?) or 6 or 7? Is it on OS X, iOS?

Comment: Safari Version 6.0.5  In an earlier version on an old iBook, 5.0.6. looks fine to me too.

Comment: SOLVED!! All I had to do was restart Safari and itworked! Sorry for the false alarm but your response put me on the right track anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

To your CSS.